# Saltstack: Beacon which reacts on pillars changes

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have a salstack setup with 1 master and about 200 minions. Minions have assigned different pillars (file based).

I want to achieve following: If there are any changes to a pillar for a minion or group of minions, a event will be send out with minionID and changed pillar to which I can react.

My first idea was, do have beacon which watches file changes in pillar files on the master. But this will not give me the affected minions. Next idea was refreshing pillars from the minion periodically and send an event on changes, but this periodic pull can create a lot of load is not what i expect from a event driven architecture.

So my question is: What is the best way to achieve this? Are there common ways to do that and I have maybe overlooked some module/feature?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider setting up a [beacon](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/beacons/index.html) to your salt-master minion that watches your pillar folder and sends an event, then you can configure a Reactor to refresh pillars with the [refresh_pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.saltutil.html#salt.modules.saltutil.refresh_pillar) module.

If you have some hierarchy of pillars based on minion id then you could also get the minion id based on the folder/file that has changed from the reactor.

In general, pillars are read/rendered each time they are requested and they are not cached or watched by SaltStack.